# What is the purpose of echo command after executing a program?

Tags: c++, compilation

Why do we exit issuing an `echo` command while executing a program?

As far as I know, the `echo` command for console windows is:

```
$ echo $
```

And for windows is:

```
$ echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: I don't see how this has anything at all to do with C++ or compilation.

Comment: This is just a way in your OS to see the return value from  `int main()`. A program that ran successfully should return 0 from main or an error code if the execution failed for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the child process ends, the set variable `ERRORLEVEL` contains an integer returned by it. `ERRORLEVEL` is measured 0 if the process was successful (i.e. return `0`). OTOH, 1 or greater if the process encountered an error.

However, I don't know what do you exactly mean by:

> echo command after executing a program

I never ran this command neither I've seen anywhere.

Comment: I've been following a book for c++ called "C++ Primer" by Lippman Stanley B. In its first chapter "Getting Started" it says we issue an echo command after successfully executing a program, but it didn't described it's purpose. Thanks for help!